# Different Meteor Simple Schemas to validate different User Roles?

Tags: meteor

I've got a bunch of different users in `Meteor.users`. I've got three different roles of users:

`profile.role = "admin"`

`profile.role = "doctor"`

`profile.role = "patient"`

They all have different schema requirements for their data fields. For example, a `patient` would need to fill out an `emergencyContact` field while the `admin` would not.

From what I understand, Simple Schema attaches a single schema to a Collection as a whole. Is there some way to define my schema such that I could have a different schema for different `roles` in my `Users` collection?

```
Meteor.users.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  profile.firstName: {
    type: String,
    label: "First Name"
  },
.
.
.
});
```

Comment: I have a similar question.  The fourth draft of http://json-schema.org describes a schema which allows this flexibility, but it is not tightly-integrated w/ Meteor at this point.  I am currently using tv4.js to validate using JSON Schema.